# How do I transform a map of A->Collection<B> to B->Collection<A> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

Is there a way, without using an intermediate map, to invert a one-to-many association?

For example: I have the following object:

`data class Change(val dependencies: Collection<Revision>)`

If I have a list of `Change` objects, I can easily generate a map using `changes.associateWith { it.dependencies }` but what if I wanted to map dependencies to all of the changes waiting on them?

Currently I'm resorting to using an intermediate `MutableMap` but I'd like to have it all sent to a standard `Map`.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the result to be a `Map<Revision, Collection<Change>>`?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `MutableMap`, all the built-in methods that create new maps from existing collections (e.g. `associateWith`) make use of an intermediate `MutableMap` under the hood to construct the new map. *Not* using a `MutableMap` would mean creating a **lot** of intermediate immutable maps, and that would allocate quite a lot of memory.

I'll assume that you mean you don't want to see any `MutableMap`s appearing *in your code*.

The idea is this: "flatten" the mapping into a collection of pairs of revisions and changes (`Pair<Revision, Change>`), then group these pairs by the revision.

```
fun transform(changes: Map<Change, List<Revision>>) =
    changes.flatMap { (change, deps) -> deps.map { it to change } }
        .groupBy({ it.first }) { it.second }
```

Or if you have a collection of `Change`s:

```
fun transform(changes: Iterable<Change>) =
    changes.flatMap { change -> 
        change.dependencies.map { it to change }
    }.groupBy({ it.first }) { it.second }
}
```

Consider adding an `asSequence` before the `map` if you don't want to create a new `List` for every change there is. That said, this still creates a lot of `Pair`s, and might take up more memory than your existing solution does.